# Manipulating map inside a map

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have some shopping items in a file, delimited by "|".

```
Adam|grocery|veggies|100.00
John|fuel|gasoline|42.60
John|grocery|veggies|20.00
```

Sales tax is 8.75%.

1. Find the total revenue for each customer.
2. For each customer find how much of the spending went to which category.
3. Show sales tax for each of the findings.

Output:

```
Total Revenue:
Adam - $100.00
John - $62.60
Tax - 14.22

Shopping by Adam:
Grocery - $100.00
Tax - $8.75

Shopping by John:
Fuel - 44.60
Grocery - 20.00
Tax - $5.47
```

I read the file with the code below and then created a `HashMap` with `String` as Key (to save customer name) and value as another `HashMap` (to save the category (name of category as key and price as value))

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GroceryStore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inFile = new File("/Users/customers.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(inFile);
            String lines = "";

            Map<String, HashMap<String, Double>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>>();

            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                lines = scan.nextLine();
                String[] wordSplit = lines.split("\\|");
                HashMap<String, Double> category = new HashMap<String, Double>();
                category.put(wordSplit[1], Double.parseDouble(wordSplit[3]));
                map.put(wordSplit[0], category);
            }

            System.out.println("Total revenue by customer: ");
            for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, Double>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working the way I was thinking and could not proceed.
In the last step of `while` loop, when `map.put` is used. That is replacing the previous entry of that person's purchase with the new purchase. But I want to have all the purchase entries for that person to be tracked. Then we should be able to show the total output and categorized output.

Could anyone help with this, you might have a different approach?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question

Comment: "It's not working" - how is it not working? what's going wrong? what's going right?

Comment: Also - you'd be better posting the full class since what you've provided has various syntax errors due to missing curly braces.

Comment: Not a homework question, it was asked to one of my friend in a interview, so I was trying to give it a shot...

Comment: I have updated the complete code and also the question, please let me know if you need more detail. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested, using python's csv library stores the rows in a dictionary with the key as the first column which in this case is the persons name.

```
import csv

data = {}

with open('/Users/customers.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
    for row in spamreader:
        data[row[0]] = row

    print data
```